# Advance Search In Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, search, datatable

i am do searching in codeigniter an its work using this query

```
$this->db->where("(h_name LIKE '".$term."%' )");
```

i would like to advanced this search like dataTable in codeigniter any way to improve the query serch all letter from the word please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This,

**Model:**

```
 Public function search($search){ 
        $this->db->like('users.email', $search);
        $this->db->or_like('users.mobile', $search); 
        $query = $this->db->get("users");
        return $result = $query->result_array();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in two ways

`$this->db->where("(h_name LIKE '%".$term."%' )");`

OR

`$this->db->where("(h_name REGEXP '".$term."' )");`